# Sentinelsat: Error trying to download from Norweigan mirror colhub.met.no

Tags: python, sentinel-hub, sentinel

I am trying to download the Sentinel 2 images over an area of Western Norway. Since the ESA archive is very slow, I am trying to use the Norwegian mirror for Sentinel instead (https://colhub.met.no/#/home).

I manage to get an excel file of the images suitable using the following code (username & password taken out):

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
import pandas as pd
import logging


logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s', level='INFO')
api = SentinelAPI('username', 'password', 'https://colhub.met.no/#/home')
dates = '[2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z TO 2019-07-01T00:00:00.000Z]'
orbit = '117'
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson("P:\Ben\hordaland_outline_simp.json"))
cloud = '[0 TO 50]'


products = api.query(footprint, dates,platformname='Sentinel-2',cloudcoverpercentage = cloud, producttype = 'S2MSI1C')


# convert to Pandas DataFrame
products_df = api.to_dataframe(products)
##products_df_sorted = products_df.sort_values(['beginposition', 'orbitdirection'], ascending=[True, True])

file_name = r"G:\Data\Raw\Sentinel\Sentinel2\1_Raw_L2A\Sentinel2_images.xlsx"
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='xlsxwriter')
# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
products_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
print "Excel file with images to be processed has been written to " + file_name
```

Then I try to download using

```
api.download_all(products_df)
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bro076\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\sentinelsat\sentinel.py", line 602, in download_all
product_info = self.download(product_id, directory_path, checksum)
  File "C:\Users\bro076\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\sentinelsat\sentinel.py", line 493, in download
product_info = self.get_product_odata(id)
  File "C:\Users\bro076\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\sentinelsat\sentinel.py", line 428, in get_product_odata
values = _parse_odata_response(response.json()['d'])
  File "C:\Users\bro076\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\sentinelsat\sentinel.py", line 1128, in _parse_odata_response
'Online': product['Online'],
KeyError: 'Online'
```

I was wondering if some of the parameters need to be tweaked when downloading from colhub.met.no, perhaps since the data is not archived in the long-term storage (Online/Offline) as is the ESA archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like the 'Online' field in OData is missing in the Norweigian mirror and this raises an error. Apparently this was resolved by setting the defaults to True in a recent bug. A temporary solution would be downgrading the package:

---

```
pip install sentinelsat==0.12
```

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks for answering in both areas!